# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView Error

Tags: android, admob

I've seen similar questions but they couldnt solve my problem. I've installed Google Play SDKs, imported as a library to my app. Following Admob instructions, I've written that code below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/relative"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.oguz.nfcdatareaderwriter.MainPage$PlaceholderFragment" >


<Button
    android:id="@+id/writeNFC"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/openingMessage"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="116dp"
    android:text="Write Custom Data to a Card" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/openingMessage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="174dp"
    android:text=".."
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

Main Activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main_page);

      // Create an ad.
    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

    // Add the AdView to the view hierarchy. The view will have no size
    // until the ad is loaded.
    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative);
    layout.addView(adView);

    // Create an ad request. Check logcat output for the hashed device ID to
    // get test ads on a physical device.
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .addTestDevice("4df1dccd39006f0f")
        .build();

    // Start loading the ad in the background.
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

Comment: How did you include Google Play Services? Did you follow http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html ?

Comment: Yeah, i follow that instruction.

Comment: now a days eclispe is not working properly. i was also getting the same error.so i switched to android studio.

Comment: may looks stupid, but clean all related projects, and try again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me it was quite difficult to use `AdMob` with Eclipse LUNA and the last SDK and ADT.

What I've found it's that you must order your Java Build Path (Right Click then properties) as folow :

```
Android Dependecies checked, Android xxx Unchecked, Android Private Librairies Checked
```

And control that in your libs folder the google-play-services.jar is inside !

Answer (score 4):

If you are getting NoClassDefFoundError then you have not properly included the GooglePlayServices library, or you have managed to exclude the classes using Proguard or similar. Try redoing the steps.